# Отличие целевого пространства имён от пространства имён по умолчанию

Tags: xml

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём заключается отличие целевого пространства имён (`targetNamespace`) от пространства имён по умолчанию?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После продолжительных раздумий, как это сформулировать, я нашёл пожалуй лучшее [описание](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35775954/5045688). Переведу его на русский.

---

Рассмотрим три схемы XSD. Все они определяют один глобальный тип и один глобальный элемент, который ссылается на этот тип.

Первая использует префикс 'xsd' для пространства имён самой схемы и пространство имён по умолчанию для `targetNamespace`:

```
<xsd:schema
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://example.com/"
  xmlns="http://example.com/">

  <xsd:element name="aGlobalElement" type="aGlobalType"/>

  <xsd:simpleType name="aGlobalType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Теперь та же схема, но определяющая и использующая префикс для целевого пространства имён:

```
<xsd:schema
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://example.com/"
  xmlns:tns="http://example.com/">

  <xsd:element name="aGlobalElement" type="tns:aGlobalType"/>

  <xsd:simpleType name="aGlobalType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

И, наконец, версия, которая использует пространство имён по умолчанию вместо 'xsd' для пространства имён самой XML-схемы:

```
<schema
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://example.com/"
  xmlns:tns="http://example.com/">

  <element name="aGlobalElement" type="tns:aGlobalType"/>

  <simpleType name="aGlobalType">
    <restriction base="string"/>
  </simpleType>
</schema>
```

Большинство авторов схем выбирают первую или последнюю, ведь если пространство имён по умолчанию доступно, то мы можем использовать его для чего-нибудь ещё.

---

Кратко: пространство имён по умолчанию (xmlns без префикса) используется в **самой XML-схеме**.
Целевое пространство имён (targetNamespace) указывает, в каком неймспейсе должны быть элементы в **XML-документе**, который валидируется этой схемой.

---

Со всем этим этим проще разобраться, если использовать хороший редактор xml. Например, редактор из состава Visual Studio выдаёт следующее (используем третий вариант схемы):

- Если убрать `targetNamespace` подчёркивает `element` с ошибкой:

  > Namespace 'http://example.com' is not available to be referenced in this schema

  То есть он видит, что `aGlobalType` объявлен в этом пространстве имён. Но не знает, в каком пространстве имён этот тип должен быть в целевом документе (который будет валидироваться этой схемой).
- Если вдобавок к этому убрать префикс `tns`, то ошибка:

  > Type 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:aGlobalType' is not declared.

  Ну, тот понятно: без префикса наш тип попадает в то же пространство имён, что и элементы схемы. А среди них нет 'aGlobalType'.

Вернём схему в рабочий вид (любая из трёх версий). Открываем документ, который валидируется этой схемой. Печатаем символ `<` - при этом редактор покажет список разрешённых элементов. Выбираем наш `aGlobalElement`, жмём <kbd>TAB</kbd> - вставится следующее определение:

```
<aGlobalElement xmlns="http://example.com/"
```

Если вместо этого напечатать `<foo` (любой желаемый префикс) и нажать <kbd>TAB</kbd>, то вставится:

```
<foo:aGlobalElement xmlns:foo="http://example.com/"
```

Становится понятно, что этот элемент **обязан** быть **именно в этом** пространстве имён (targetNamespace), чтобы документ являлся валидным в соответствии с нашей схемой.

Comment: А разве во втором случае не должно быть name="tns:aGlobalElement" и  name="tns:aGlobalType"?

Comment: @Ksenia - Нет. Ведь это просто имена. В каком пространстве имён они _будут_ определены, как раз и зависит от `targetNamespace`. К тому же, в имени не может быть символа двоеточия.

Comment: Ой, точно. Но в чём всё-таки разница между targetNamespace и xmlns? Как я поняла, xmlns используется для того, чтобы можно было не указывать префикс перед элементом, именем типа и т.д., а для чего тогда функционально нужен targetNamespace?

Comment: @Ksenia - Обратите внимание на третий пример. В нем дефолтный неймспейс используется для самой схемы. А целевой неймспейс отличается. Поэтому приходится задавать для него префикс.

Comment: Это я понимаю, но для чего нужно targetNamespace? Т.е. что бы изменилось, если в третьем примере строки targetNamespace="http://example.com/" вообще бы не было?

Comment: @Ksenia - описал как мог. Смотрите обновление ответа.

Comment: спасибо, теперь всё стало гораздо понятнее!